# What are the spoils that Jesus will divide with the strong, and who are the strong? Isaiah 53:12

Tags: jesus, isaiah

Isaiah 53:12 (NIV)

> Therefore I **[God]**  will give him **[Jesus]** a portion among the great, 
>   and he will divide the spoils with the strong,[b]because he poured out
>   his life unto death, and was numbered with the transgressors.For he
>   bore the sin of many, and made intercession for the transgressors

The words [God] and [Jesus] in bold are mine.

The prophetic words of Isaiah  had its fullfilment in the name of Jesus, for he was excecuted as a lawbreaker alongside two robbers. Mark 15:27

The verse raises some questions.

**1/  Therefore I [God]  will give him [Jesus] a portion among the great.** **Who are the great?**

**2/ What are the spoils that Jesus will divide with the strong, and who are the strong?**

Answer (score 4):

From dictionary the verb spoil means transitive archaic

> To strip (someone who has been killed or defeated) of
>   their arms or armour.
>   As a noun the word spoil means:
>
> noun (plural spoils)(Also in plural: spoils) Plunder taken from an
>   enemy or victim.

After victory in a battle the spoil was divided to the great men of war

Numbers 31:52,53

> 52 And all the gold of the offering that they offered up to the LORD,
>   of the captains of thousands, and of the captains of hundreds, was
>   sixteen thousand seven hundred and fifty shekels.
>
> 53 For the men of war had taken spoil, every man for himself.)

Spoil is a present given to the deserving after victory in a warfare

1 Samuel 30:26

> 26 And when David came to Ziklag, he sent of the spoil unto the elders
>   of Judah, even to his friends, saying, Behold a present for you of the
>   spoil of the enemies of the LORD;

In battles they used to have spoil of cities:

Joshua 11:13,14

> 13 But as for the cities that stood still in their strength, Israel
>   burned none of them, save Hazor only; that did Joshua burn.
>
> 14 And all the spoil of these cities, and the cattle, the children of
>   Israel took for a prey unto themselves; but every man they smote with
>   the edge of the sword, until they had destroyed them, neither left
>   they any to breathe.

Spoil also has spiritual connotation:

Psalm 119:161,162

> 161 SCHIN. Princes have persecuted me without a cause: but my heart
>   standeth in awe of thy word.
>
> 162 I rejoice at thy word, as one that findeth great spoil.

Spoil is used in the scripture to mean destroying the works of Satan.

Mark 3:27

> 27 No man can enter into a strong man's house, and spoil his goods,
>   except he will first bind the strong man; and then he will spoil his
>   house.

Dividing the spoil with the great can be seen as the reward given to the gallant soldiers of the cross who took sides with Jesus in the spiritual battle against the enemy.
At his coming he will divide the spoils with the great:

Luke 19:17-19

> 17 And he said unto him, Well, thou good servant: because thou hast
>   been faithful in a very little, have thou authority over ten cities.
>
> 18 And the second came, saying, Lord, thy pound hath gained five
>   pounds.
>
> 19 And he said likewise to him, Be thou also over five cities.

Revelation 2:26-28

> 26 And he that overcometh, and keepeth my works unto the end, to him
>   will I give power over the nations:
>
> 27 And he shall rule them with a rod of iron; as the vessels of a
>   potter shall they be broken to shivers: even as I received of my
>   Father.
>
> 28 And I will give him the morning star.

Comment: @ Samuel: Appreciate you comments  and effort.Yes, God does not forget faithful men of antiquity like Noah, Abraham mentioned by Paul in Hebrews chapter 11 and has promised them a portion in his coming new world.( Hebrews 11:13-16.) Like Jesus who poured his life unto death, his faithful apostles also followed in  his footsteps, and in the verse are referred to as the strong, and it is with those he will share the spoils. (Ephesians 4:8-12, Rev. 3:21) The spoils are men and women of faith ,Revelation 14:1.